# Unable to connect to phpmyadmin or to database from mysql workbench on remote computer

Tags: php, mysql, windows, phpmyadmin, wamp

I've looked around and found many articles on how to get this to work but nothing I've tried has been successful.

I have a Windows 8 (64-bit) vm on a local network and am trying to connect to it to edit the Database. Through Microsoft Remote Desktop I am able to connect to phpmyadmin without a problem, but can't connect to it via browser on the computer that is running MRD. I've tried adding a second user, and set the host column to % for both the root and secondary users. I've also created a password for root.

I have tried a lot of the different Allow/Deny directives in the .conf files in Wamp's Alias folder. The examples I've seen are a bit different though, as theirs just show the directives, while I have this in the confs:

```
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    </IfDefine>
```

Been pounding my head against the wall for a couple of weeks now. While I can access the DB via Remote Desktop, I am not the only user of the VM and it's more efficient if I can access it via my computer, and even better if I can use Workbench.

Forgot to mention: While I need the above for myself, it will also need to be available for any users of the network, even via VPN.

Comment: Is wampserver started? - Stupid question, just checkin'!

Comment: Yup. Started and restarted several times.

Comment: @Eric... have u granted access privileges to mysql db remotely ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an SSH tunnel to forward your localhost:13306 to remote:3306 using

```
ssh -L13306:dbhost:3306 user@remotehost
```

This will listen on port `13306` on your localhost, forward connections over the ssh tunnel to `remotehost`, where they are then forwarded to `dbhost` port `3306`.
If that database runs on the remote machine itself, use `localhost` for `dbhost`, which will be simply `127.0.0.1` as seen from the remote machine:

```
ssh -L13306:localhost:3306
```

If you're on windows, you can set up SSH tunnels with Putty.

Once you've logged in, you can connect to the remote database by connecting to `localhost:13306` on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

After some desperation digging I finally found the problem. I was able to change a couple of settings in phpmyadmin's config.php from localhost to the web server URL. I had done this once before so not sure why it didn't work the first time. Might have been that I hadn't changed host to % in the db.